# How to embed React app with react-router into existing web app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Currently, I have fully workable react application with react-router, redux and other stuff. Now, I need to embed my application into any other web app

I'm using BrowserRouter at the moment. I found solution how to embed application, but it routing works wrong, because it expects the following URL:
https://my-app.com/home
But actual URL is: https://other-awesome-app/apps

The question is: How to handle routing of existing(embedded) react app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe to embed your react-app in another web app, and you can set it to pick up the parent's web page URL routing!